# Update c++ model on qml delegate visual model change

Tags: c++, qt, qml

There's a simple `QStandardItemModel` defined in c++ which I am displaying in a `QML` `ListView` via custom `Delegate`s and a `DelegateModel`. The ListView can be reordered via Drag'n Drop:

```
// The DropArea is part of the delegate `comp_container`
DropArea{
    anchors{fill: parent}
    keys: ["pageitem"]
    onEntered: {
        let from = drag.source.DelegateModel.itemsIndex
        let to = dragAreaPage.DelegateModel.itemsIndex
        if ( pageItemDragOperationStartIndex === -1 ){
            pageItemDragOperationStartIndex = from
        }
        pageItemDragOperationFinalIndex = to
        console.log(from + "->" + to)
        visualModel.items.move(from,to)
    }
}
```

Here is the delegate model and `pageproxymodel` is the c++ model.

```
DelegateModel {
    id: visualModel
    model: pageproxymodel
    delegate: comp_container
}
```

How do I want to update the c++ model?
The delegate's top level item is a `MouseArea` and I handle the reordering in the release handler:

```
onReleased: {
    if ( pageItemDragOperationStartIndex !== -1 && pageItemDragOperationFinalIndex !== -1 ){
        console.log("Page item final drag operation: " + pageItemDragOperationStartIndex + "->" + pageItemDragOperationFinalIndex)
        pageproxymodel.move(pageItemDragOperationStartIndex, pageItemDragOperationFinalIndex)
        pageItemDragOperationStartIndex = -1
        pageItemDragOperationFinalIndex = -1
    }
}
```

The c++ model's `move` function forwards the call to this handler:

```
bool PageModel::moveRow(const QModelIndex &sourceParent,
                        int sourceRow,
                        const QModelIndex &destinationParent,
                        int destinationChild)
{
    if ( sourceRow < 0 || sourceRow > rowCount()-1 ||
         destinationChild < 0 || destinationChild > rowCount() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    beginMoveRows(sourceParent, sourceRow, sourceRow, destinationParent, destinationChild);
 
    QList<QStandardItem*> rowItems = takeRow(sourceRow);
    insertRow(destinationChild, rowItems);

    endMoveRows();

    return true;
}
```

With the above c++ model code, it crashes at the release handler in QML:

[image]

I've tried other things to see the effect, no crashes, but also not the expected behaviour.

- deleting a single row (which deletes 2 (!) rows in the QML ListView)
- deleting a single row without begin/end calls (deletes 1 rows in the QML ListView, but can't be right)
- remove and insert a single row without begin/end calls (QML ListView looks fine for a while but comes out of sync after a few moves)

Basically all I want to do is to save the ListView state via the c++ model, after all that is a standard use case and something simple must be wrong on my side, yet I can't see it.

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html or https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html. The latter is somewhat harder to get your head around, but, the advantage is it is a QML only solution and you can do some sophisticated filtering / sorting - reordering without requiring the underlying model to be modified.

Comment: The `begin*` and `end*` functions are for when you are managing the data storage in the model (ie. you have a vector<MyClass> somewhere storing the data). With `QStandardItemModel`, the model is the one in charge of the data (and thus, you don't call begin/end functions). You would use one of the abstract model types (like `QAbstractListModel`) if you want to store and move the data yourself. I think you should be able to to `takeRow` and `insertRow` (without begin/end calls), just know that your destination index might change as a result of `takeRow`.

Comment: @StephenQuan - I am using the DelegateModel. But I also want to update the underlying c++ model to be updated at the end of the visual move operation, to initiate a save() call.

Comment: @DeanJohnson Thanks for pointing out that begin/end is not needed for a `QStandardItemModel`, I did not know that. Makes sense. I have also tried without those calls but after a while the c++ model was in a different order than the visual one. Might be there is still another bug. And another idea might be to try with a custom vector implementation and begin/end calls.

Comment: Are you sure your destination index is correct after the `takeRow` call? Let's say your model stored increasing numbers from 0..N and you wanted to re-arrange the list to be 1,2,0,3,4,... (move the 0). You would call `takeRow(0)`. Your destination index is 3 in the original list, but after `takeRow` the list has changed and you would want to insert into index 2 with insertRow(2, ...).

Answer (score 1):

One thing I like to do with `DelegateModel` makes use of `DelegateModelGroup`. By declaring a group named "all", it introduces an attached property `allIndex` which is useful for tracking an item after it has been reordered. The following example implements a `DelegateModel` with both `MouseArea` and `DropArea`. When in dragging mode, I disable all `MouseArea` so that the `DropArea` can have a chance at responding.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    property int activeMouseArea: -1
    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: 420
        height: parent.height
        model: SampleDelegateModel { }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
    footer: Text { id: dbg }
}

// SampleData.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ListModel {
    ListElement { name: "Steve Jobs" }
    ListElement { name: "Jeff Bezos" }
    ListElement { name: "Bill Gates" }
    ListElement { name: "Elon Musk" }
}

// SampleDelegateModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQml.Models

DelegateModel {
    id: delegateModel
    model: SampleData { }
    delegate: SampleDelegate { }
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: allItems
            name: "all"
            includeByDefault: true
        }
    ]
    filterOnGroup: "all"
    function moveItem(from, to) {
        dbg.text = `Debugging: moveItem(${from},${to})`;
        allItems.move(from, to);
    }
}

// SampleDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQml.Models

Rectangle {
    property int allIndex: DelegateModel.allIndex
    width: 400
    height: labelText.height + 20
    border.color: "grey"
    z: mouseArea.drag.active || mouseArea.pressed ? 2 : 1
    property int dragTo: -1
    Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active

    Text {
        id: labelText
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: allIndex + ": [" + index + "] " + name
    }

    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onEntered: drag.source.dragTo = allIndex
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: parent
        property point startPoint
        enabled: activeMouseArea === -1
        onPressed: {
            activeMouseArea = allIndex;
            dragTo = -1;
            startPoint = Qt.point(parent.x, parent.y);
        }
        onReleased: {
            activeMouseArea = -1;
            [parent.x,parent.y] = [startPoint.x, startPoint.y];
            Qt.callLater(delegateModel.moveItem, allIndex, dragTo);
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake:
The `pageItemDragOperationStartIndex` and `pageItemDragOperationFinalIndex` variables where part of each delegate, but not of the page.
Also, as was pointed out in the comments, using a `QStandardItemModel` it is not necessary to call the `begin/end` functions. Now it works like a charm.